# Seaborn heatmaps in subplots - align x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I am trying to plot a figure containing two **subplots**, a **seaborn heatmap** and simple **matplotlib lines**. However, when sharing the x-axis for both plots, they do not align as can be seen in this figure:

[image: figure]

It would seem that the problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050855/align-x-axis-ticks-in-shared-subplots-of-heatmap-and-line-plots-using-seaborn-an), but when displaying `ax[0].get_xticks()` and `ax[1].get_xticks()` I get the same positions, so I don't know what to change. And in my picture the the deviation seems to be more than a 0.5 shift.

What am I doing wrong?

The code I used to plot the figure is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M_1=np.random.random((15,15))
M_2=np.random.random((15,15))

L_1=np.random.random(15)
L_2=np.random.random(15)

x=range(15)

cmap = sns.color_palette("hot", 100)
sns.set(style="white")

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='col', figsize=(10, 12))

ax[0].plot(x,L_1,'-', marker='o',color='tab:orange')
sns.heatmap(M_1, cmap=cmap, vmax=np.max(M_1), center=np.max(M_1)/2., square=False, ax=ax[1])
```

Comment: You can align it by using `cbar=False` in the heatmap code.

Comment: I assume the colorbar is rather essential. How about creating a [gridspec pattern](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec03.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec03-py) that subdivides the lower subplot in an area for the heatmap and a smaller area designated to the colorbar, then plot the colorbar in this designated ax space using the `cbar_ax` parameter of heatmap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Mr-T 's comment is spot on. The easiest would be to create the axes beforehand instead of letting `heatmap()` shrink your axes in order to make room for the colorbar.

There is the added complication that the labels for the heatmap are not actually placed at [0,1,...] but are in the middle of each cell at [0.5, 1.5, ...]. So if you want your upper plot to align with the labels at the bottom (and with the center of each cell), you may have to shift your plot by 0.5 units to the right:

```
M_1=np.random.random((15,15))
M_2=np.random.random((15,15))
L_1=np.random.random(15)
L_2=np.random.random(15)
x=np.arange(15)

cmap = sns.color_palette("hot", 100)
sns.set(style="white")

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[100,5]})
ax[0,1].remove()  # remove unused upper right axes
ax[0,0].plot(x+0.5,L_1,'-', marker='o',color='tab:orange')
sns.heatmap(M_1, cmap=cmap, vmax=np.max(M_1), center=np.max(M_1)/2., square=False, ax=ax[1,0], cbar_ax=ax[1,1])
```

[image]