# Subplotting multiple heatmaps using seaborn results in subplots of varying sizes

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am relatively new to Python and currently facing some challenges with creating heatmaps using the Seaborn library. My goal is to generate five heatmaps stacked on top of each other.

However, I've encountered an issue where the heatmaps are not uniform in size; they vary in dimensions. Note that all the heatmaps have the same number of columns (samples), but they differ in the number of rows (gene names). Thus, they should have the same width.

Pic of the problem:

[image: Pic of the problem]

This is my code:

```
# Plot heatmap using only numeric columns
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(8, 20))  # 5 rows, 1 column

# Adjust spacing between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)

# Plot heatmaps for each complex
colorbar_ax = None
for ax, df, show_colorbar in zip(
    axs, [quantity_complex_I_df, quantity_complex_II_df, quantity_complex_III_df, quantity_complex_IV_df, quantity_complex_V_df], 
         [True, False, False, False, False]):
        sns.heatmap(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']), 
                    cmap='coolwarm', 
                    center=1, 
                    annot=False, 
                    fmt=".2f", 
                    square=True, 
                    robust=True, 
                    cbar=show_colorbar, 
                    cbar_ax=None if show_colorbar else colorbar_ax, 
                    ax=ax)
        # Remove x-axis ticks and labels
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        
# Adjust the size of the colorbar for Complex I
colorbar_ax.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)  # Adjust the font size of the colorbar labels

axs[0].set_ylabel('Complex I')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Complex II')
axs[2].set_ylabel('Complex III')
axs[3].set_ylabel('Complex IV')
axs[4].set_ylabel('Complex V')

plt.show()
```

Things I tried but did not work (or could not make them to work)

[Seaborn heatmaps in subplots - align x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037113/seaborn-heatmaps-in-subplots-align-x-axis)

1. Pass  sharex = "col" to subplots()

`fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(8, 20), sharex = "col")`

2. Pass aspect='auto' to sns.heatmap():

```
for ax, df, show_colorbar in zip(
    axs, [quantity_complex_I_df, quantity_complex_II_df, quantity_complex_III_df, quantity_complex_IV_df, quantity_complex_V_df], 
         [True, False, False, False, False]):
        sns.heatmap(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']), 
                    cmap='coolwarm', 
                    center=1, 
                    annot=False, 
                    fmt=".2f", 
                    **square=False**, 
                    robust=True, 
                    cbar=show_colorbar, 
                    cbar_ax=None if show_colorbar else colorbar_ax, 
                    ax=ax,
                    **aspect='auto'**)
        # Remove x-axis ticks and labels
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Outcome:

[Pic when adding aspect = "auto"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGXYf.png)

3. Add ax.set_aspect('equal') withing the for loop:

```
for ax, df, show_colorbar in zip(
    axs, [quantity_complex_I_df, quantity_complex_II_df, quantity_complex_III_df, quantity_complex_IV_df,
quantity_complex_V_df], 
         [True, False, False, False, False]):
        sns.heatmap(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']), 
                    cmap='coolwarm', 
                    center=1, 
                    annot=False, 
                    fmt=".2f", 
                    square=True, 
                    robust=True, 
                    cbar=show_colorbar, 
                    cbar_ax=None if show_colorbar else colorbar_ax, 
                    ax=ax)

       ** ax.set_aspect('equal')**
        # Remove x-axis ticks and labels
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

Comment: In `sns.heatmap()`, `aspect='auto'` conflicts with `square=True`. It should be `square=False`.

Comment: Thank you very much JohanC. I tried that, but the new figure is empty (I added a picture to my initial post).

Comment: You probably got some error message written out. Did you see it? Try to set `square=False` and remove `aspect=...`. You also need to remove `ax.set_aspect('equal')` to prevent the pixels made square again.